# WiPi not going into monitor mode

Tags: raspbian, linux

Ok so on my raspberry pi using the WiPi I am trying to set it to monitor mode using.
Sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
Sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor

But it says SET failed on device wlan0; Device or resource busy. Any help?

So even after doing sudo service ifplugd stop, it still says device or resource busy when I try and put it in monitor mode :( why is this?!

EDIT: somehow doing Sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
Sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor but separating them with a semi Colon works wtf. And I even did iwconfig and it said its in monitor mode

Comment: Try "sudo service ifplugd stop" first..

Comment: @m0atz it's still says it is busy

Comment: and it didn't take it offline either :/

Comment: Just seen your edit and that was my next suggestion based on googling. Weird one don't know why tbh

Comment: I had to kill ifplugd as well as stopping it. sudo /etc/init.d/ifplugd stop ;
sudo killall ifplugd